# How to work out how to include jquery plugin with CLI project?

Tags: aurelia

So my existing flow for adding dependencies to a project created with the CLI so far is this:

1) npm install

2) Open aurelia.json and try adding name of package eg:

```
"dependencies": [
...
"jquery.scrollTo",
```

This works a lot of the time. If this does not work I try the more verbose method like so:

```
  {
    "name": "jquery.scrollto",
    "path": "../node_modules/jquery.scrollto",
    "main": "jquery.scrollTo",
    "deps": [
      "jquery"
    ]
  }
```

One of the two ways above usually work but then there's some which need prepending. Like so:

```
"prepend": [
  "node_modules/jquery.scrollto/jquery.scrollTo.js"
```

I am trying to install a plugin to jquery, "jquery.scrollTo" however none of the methods above work. As such i'd like to get a better understanding.

prepending says jquery is not loaded and the other methods do not seem to extend jquery and fails at "run time"

I have also tried various imports but would prefer this to be global without importing even if it did work

```
import { scrollTo } from 'jquery.scrollto';

export class Menu
{
    constructor(){

    }

    scrollToPage(elementId:string)
    {
        debugger;
        $("body").scrollTo($(elementId)); //scrollTo not found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prepend both, jQuery and ScrollTo. Like this:

```
"prepend": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "node_modules/jquery.scrollto/jquery.scrollTo.js"
]
```

Now you can use `scrollTo` without having to import it.

Comment: Yep, this really is the preferred way. Not everything plays nice as a module, and the prepend option really helps make dealing with this very simple for JavaScript-only stuff.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing to get it working, but thought it was not the recommended way for some reason. No worries, i'm happy to go with this.